# Unable to POST data in node.js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, https

I am requesting a https post method with a data but my data is not going with the request and thats why service is giving error, so how can i change my code so that it will get to the server , here is my code

```
var https = require('https');
var querystring = require('querystring');
connect();
function connect(){

var postData = querystring.stringify({
  'application': 'QF2',
    'client': 'COMMAND',
    'userId': 'devicexxx',
    'operation': 'at-cmd',
    'payload': 'dfdfdfdf',
    'messageId': '123e454567-e89b-12d3-a456-42665544'
});
var options = {
  hostname: 'cus.inco.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/portal/action/dev',
  method: 'POST',
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': postData.length
  }
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
  //console.log("headers: ", res.headers);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function(d) {
    console.log(d)
  });
});
req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`write()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_write_chunk_encoding_callback) your POST data before you end the request.

```
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

Comment: Thanks, Trott it works, but i got one another problem of json format my service is replyed with error parsing json, can you help me on that?

Comment: If solving this problem uncovered a second problem, post a new question.